# Python Merge Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, merge, mergesort

This seems to be working now... Open criticism welcome.  Ty tsroten.

```
debug = 1
#List to be merged
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

#Artificial variables from calling function
p=0
r=len(A)
q=int(((p+r)/2)-1)

#List to append merged values
B=[]

#End of list
end=len(A)

if debug:
    print ('Mid: %d\n' % (q))
    print ('End: %d' % (end))

#Left and Right lists with sentinels
L=A[:q+1]
R=A[q+1:]
L.append(None)
R.append(None)

#Init counters
i=k=j=l=0

if debug:
    print ('A:%s' %(A))
    print ('\n')
    print ('L:%s' %(L))
    print ('R:%s' %(R))
    print ('\n')

#Merge Left and Right lists
for k in A:
    if debug:
        print ('Iteration:%d' % (l))
        l+=1
        print ('i=%d, j=%d' % (i, j))
        print ('B:%s' %(B))
        print ('\n')
    if L[i] is not None and L[i]<=R[j]:
        B.append(L[i])
        i+=1
    else:
        B.append(R[j])
        j+=1

print ('Result:',B)
```

I am trying to write a merge algorithm in Python but I keep running into this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Scripts/mergeSort.py", line 19, in <module>
    if L[i]<=R[j] and i<mid:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have looked at other algorithms but they don't seem to have the same problem.  Please help.

```
A=[2,4,5,7,1,3,7,8,9]  
B=[]


end=len(A)  
mid=int(end/2)

L=A[:mid]  
R=A[mid+1:]

i=k=j=0

for k in A:  
    if L[i]<=R[j] and i<mid:  
        B.append(L[i])  
        i+=1  
    elif j<end:  
        B.append(R[j])  
        j+=1  

print (B)
```

Comment: Any issues with `B = L + R`, or are you just exploring alternatives?

Comment: It is more of an exercise to refresh my algorithmic knowledge rather than finding the easiest method.  I will eventually tie this together for a merge-sort algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop goes through all the items in `A`, which is longer than `L` or `R`. So, at some point, `i` and `j` become greater than the length of `L` and `R`. At that point, referencing `L[i]` or `R[j]` raises an `IndexError`.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I had thought the conditionals 'i<mid' and 'j<end' would prevent it from going out of bounds. The counter 'k' isn't used inside the for loop and should run without error.  I did add one to both L and R and the bounds error went away, but if I add another integer to the array, it doesn't merge properly.

Comment: `len(R) != end` So, does `j < end` really help you?

Comment: i made the change from j<end to j<len(R) which yields the same result.

Comment: The `IndexError` refers to `L[i]`, not `R[j]`. Let's say `i == mid - 1`. Then, it satisfies the conditional and gets incremented so that `i == mid`. Now, `L[i]` raises an `IndexError`.

Comment: Why don't you add some basic `print()` calls to your code to help you debug. Maybe a `print(mid)` at the beginning. Then, at the beginning of the `for` loop: a `print('i: %s, j: %s' % (i, j))`, a `print('L[i]: %s' % L[i])`, and a  `print('R[j]: %s' % R[j])`.

Comment: Okay, so the code seems to be working...I will post what I have.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether i and j are inbounds before calling that index.